# Solving SDP as an NLP with squared slack variable

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to solve an SDP problem in the following standard form:

\begin{matrix}
        \min_{X} & \text{tr}(CX) \\
        s.t & \text{tr}(A X) = b\\
            & X \succeq 0.\\
        \end{matrix}

However I want to write the problem as an NLP and solve using general NLP solver instead of solving and SDP problem (because later in my problem $b$ will be a quadratic variable). For that I introduced a quadratic constraint $X = L L^\top$ and removed the semidefinite constraint as follows:

\begin{matrix}
        \min_{X,L} & \text{tr}(C X) \\
        s.t & \text{tr}(A X) = b\\
            & X = LL^\top.\\
        \end{matrix}

The problem I get is the solver fails to solve such a problem and returns an infeasible result, even when I use GUROBI, using the nonconvex solver. For some particular problem, knowing that the Cholesky decomposition has nonnegative elements, I added a constraint $L\geq 0$ and the results were correct.

Is there a good way to cast SDP as an NLP other than the quadratic slack constraint? Or maybe there is a way to improve the performance of the current method?

Comment: Can you provide details on the Gurobi formulation, and show the log output of the run which reported infeasible without $L \ge 0$ constraint, and found optimal solution when $L \ge 0$ was added? Perhaps you made an error, or misinterpreted the results, or Gurobi encountered numerical difficulties which were avoided when $L \ge 0$ was added? BTW, I believe you should only be constraining the diagonal of L to be $\ge 0$, not all the elements of $L$.

Comment: I formulated the problem in YALMIP in the following way:

A1 = [1 0 1;0 3 7; 1 7 5];
A2 = [0 2 8;2 6 0; 8 0 4];
C = [1 2 3; 2 9 0; 3 0 7];
b1 = 11; b2 = 19;
X=sdpvar(3,3);
obj = trace(C*X);
const = [trace(A1*X) == b1, trace(A2*X)==b2, X>=0];
optimize(const, obj, sdpsettings('solver','mosek'));
obj_mosek = value(obj);

Y=sdpvar(3,3,'full');
obj = trace(C*(Y*Y'));
const = [trace(A1*(Y*Y')) == b1, trace(A2*(Y*Y'))==b2, Y>=0];
optimize(const, obj, sdpsettings('solver','gurobi'));
obj_gurobi = value(obj);

Comment: I checked my code and I get the optimal solution when I constrain only the diagonal elements to be nonnegative! Thank you for the comment!

Comment: You should post copy and pastable code, and all output, at https://groups.google.com/g/yalmip .Johan will get to the bottom of it.